# How to import complex json data in Hive

Tags: json, dictionary, hive

In input, I have this file json to import on hive:

```
[
    {
        "code": "ACPBC3P",
        "libelle": "Bon de commande Prime de satisfaction ACP",
        "libelleCourt": "Bon de commande Prime de satisfaction ACP",
        "libelleLong": "Bon de commande Prime de satisfaction ACP",
        "dureeStockage": 24,
        "dureeArchivage": 96,
        "dureeEpuration": 120,
        "dureeStockageReelle": 24,
        "dureeArchivageReelle": 96,
        "dureeEpurationReelle": 120,
        "typologie": {
            "code": "ACP",
            "libelle": "ACP - Activ'projet"
        },
        "sousTypologie": {
            "code": "ACPBC3P",
            "libelle": "BC3P - Bon de commande Prime de satisfaction"
        }
    },
    {
        "code": "ACPC1",
        "libelle": "C1 - Demande d'avoir",
        "libelleCourt": "C1 - Demande d'avoir",
        "libelleLong": "C1 - Demande d'avoir",
        "dureeStockage": 36,
        "dureeArchivage": 84,
        "dureeEpuration": 120,
        "dureeStockageReelle": 36,
        "dureeArchivageReelle": 84,
        "dureeEpurationReelle": 120,
        "typologie": {
            "code": "ACP",
            "libelle": "ACP - Activ'projet"
        },
        "sousTypologie": {
            "code": "ACPC1",
            "libelle": "C1 - Demande d'avoir"
        }
    },
    {
        "code": "ACPC2",
        "libelle": "C2 - Relance fournisseur",
        "libelleCourt": "C2 - Relance fournisseur",
        "libelleLong": "C2 - Relance fournisseur",
        "dureeStockage": 36,
        "dureeArchivage": 84,
        "dureeEpuration": 120,
        "dureeStockageReelle": 36,
        "dureeArchivageReelle": 84,
        "dureeEpurationReelle": 120,
        "typologie": {
            "code": "ACP",
            "libelle": "ACP - Activ'projet"
        },
```

I tried to capture this information with this complex type:

```
ARRAY <STRUCT <`code`: STRING,` libelle`: STRING, `libelleCourt`: STRING,` libelleLong`: STRING, `storage duration`: INT, `Archive duration` INT, `dureeEpuration`: INT,` dureeStockageReelle`: INT, `dureeArchivageReelle`: INT,` dureeEpurationReelle`: INT, `typologie`: STRUCT <` code` STRING, `libelle` STRING>,` sousTypologie`: STRUCT <`code`: STRING,` libelle`: STRING>, `modeCapture`: STRUCT <` code`: STRING, `libelle`: STRING>,` master`: STRING, `codeActivite`: STRING >> but unfortunately it do not work !

 ARRAY <STRUCT <`code`: STRING,` libelle`: STRING, `libelleCourt`: STRING,` libelleLong`: STRING, `storage duration`: INT, `Archive duration` INT, `dureeEpuration`: INT,` dureeStockageReelle`: INT, `dureeArchivageReelle`: INT,` dureeEpurationReelle`: INT, `typologie`: STRUCT <` code` STRING, `libelle` STRING>,` sousTypologie`: STRUCT <`code`: STRING,` libelle`: STRING>, `modeCapture`: STRUCT <` code`: STRING, `libelle`: STRING>,` master`: STRING, `codeActivite`: STRING >> but unfortunately it do not work !
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned anything about error faced. In general, there are two things to note when using JSON SerDe.

1. *org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.JsonSerDe* does not support JSON data that starts with square bracket '['
2. JsonSerDe is based on the text SerDe and each newline is considered as a new record

**Valid format:**

```
{"world_rank": "1","country": "China","population": "1388232694","World": "0.185"},
{"world_rank": "2","country": "India","population": "1342512706","World": "0.179"},
{"world_rank": "3","country": "U.S.","population": "326474013","World": "0.043"},
{"world_rank": "4","country": "Indonesia","population": "263510146","World": "0.035"}
```

**Invalid format 1:**

```
[
{"world_rank": "1","country": "China","population": "1388232694","World": "0.185"},
{"world_rank": "2","country": "India","population": "1342512706","World": "0.179"},
{"world_rank": "3","country": "U.S.","population": "326474013","World": "0.043"},
{"world_rank": "4","country": "Indonesia","population": "263510146","World": "0.035"}
]
```

**Invalid format 2:**

```
  {
    "world_rank": "1",
    "country": "China",
    "population": "1388232694",
    "World": "0.185"
  },
  {
    "world_rank": "2",
    "country": "India",
    "population": "1342512706",
    "World": "0.179"
  },
  {
    "world_rank": "3",
    "country": "U.S.",
    "population": "326474013",
    "World": "0.043"
  },
  {
    "world_rank": "4",
    "country": "Indonesia",
    "population": "263510146",
    "World": "0.035"
  }
```

**Input data should be pre-processed to below format before loading it into Hive table**

```
{"code":"ACPBC3P","libelle":"Bon de commande Prime de satisfaction ACP","libelleCourt":"Bon de commande Prime de satisfaction ACP","libelleLong":"Bon de commande Prime de satisfaction ACP","dureeStockage":24,"dureeArchivage":96,"dureeEpuration":120,"dureeStockageReelle":24,"dureeArchivageReelle":96,"dureeEpurationReelle":120,"typologie":{"code":"ACP","libelle":"ACP - Activ'projet"},"sousTypologie":{"code":"ACPBC3P","libelle":"BC3P - Bon de commande Prime de satisfaction"}},
{"code":"ACPC1","libelle":"C1 - Demande d'avoir","libelleCourt":"C1 - Demande d'avoir","libelleLong":"C1 - Demande d'avoir","dureeStockage":36,"dureeArchivage":84,"dureeEpuration":120,"dureeStockageReelle":36,"dureeArchivageReelle":84,"dureeEpurationReelle":120,"typologie":{"code":"ACP","libelle":"ACP - Activ'projet"},"sousTypologie":{"code":"ACPC1","libelle":"C1 - Demande d'avoir"}}
{"code":"ACPC2","libelle":"C2 - Relance fournisseur","libelleCourt":"C2 - Relance fournisseur","libelleLong":"C2 - Relance fournisseur","dureeStockage":36,"dureeArchivage":84,"dureeEpuration":120,"dureeStockageReelle":36,"dureeArchivageReelle":84,"dureeEpurationReelle":120,"typologie":{"code":"ACP","libelle":"ACP - Activ'projet"}}
```

**DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE data (
code STRING,
libelle STRING,
libelleCourt STRING,
libelleLong STRING,
dureeStockage INT,
dureeArchivage INT,
dureeEpuration INT,
dureeStockageReelle INT,
dureeArchivageReelle INT,
dureeEpurationReelle INT,
typologie struct<code: STRING, libelle: STRING>,
sousTypologie struct<code: STRING, libelle: STRING>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

**Queries to select data:**

```
select soustypologie.code from data;
select typologie.libelle from data;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, i have try your suggestion but his doesn't work, the error message : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Cannot validate serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.JsonSerDe, after i have try with this serde : serde "org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe" the installation worked but i dont have data